# Reading from stdin `dd` copies more data than reading the same thing from file

Tags: dd, iso, xz

I encountered weird behaviour of the `dd` tool:

1. I downloaded compressed "newsystem.iso.xz".
2. I ran `xz -d --stdout newsystem.iso.xz | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M conv=sync`.
3. The decompressed "*.iso" file weights about 4.5GB. I expect this to fit on the usb. Instead `dd` fails with "Not enough space" error, saying that it wrote 8.1GB (the usb is about 8GB)

But then I downloaded the already decompressed "*.iso" and ran:

1. `dd if=newsystem.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M conv=sync`
2. Command succeeds after writing the expected 4.5GB.

I can verify that `xz -d --stdout newsystem.iso.xz | shash512sum` is the same as `shash512sum newsystem.iso`.

The `sync` option means

> sync   pad  every  input block with NULs to ibs-size

The `dd` version is "GNU coreutils 9.0" and the iso image is "FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I find a free moment after I'm done with booting I can check `cat "newsystem.iso" | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M conv=sync`.

Comment: You probably need `iflag=fullblock`.

Comment: that's what `conv=sync` does on incomplete reads from a pipe, it does not make sense here and you probably want to [avoid it in general](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171)